# How to overcome the u200d unicode while reading excel files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

The excel file contains Indian language data. The excel file is being read but while displaying the content it shows \u200d in between. I need to avoid it to do further processing of data. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = 'This is some \u200d text that has to be cleaned\u200d! it\u200d annoying!'
s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

output :

This is some  text that has to be cleaned! it annoying!'
```